# What is cold pressed method to extract Juice?

Tags: juicing

Yesterday I came to know about the term when I was looking for some juice. They were stating that we will deliver `cold pressed Juice`. So that make me wonder about what is Cold Pressed method and how can we extract juice using that way.

Comment: Sounds ambiguous or gimmicky or both. Not pasterurised? Low temperatures? Pressed rather than pulped and centrifuged?

Answer (score 8):

Cold pressing is as the name implies, to press(instead of blending) juice from a fruit while minimizing heat generation. You can buy these cold pressing juicers from the market as they're quite common nowadays.

Cold pressers from the market will likely have a rotating core (think drill bit) fixed in a tube structure. Drop your fruit from the top, and juice comes out after it gets pressed by the slowly rotating core.

The need for cold pressing juices likely came about when people thought that the traditional style of juice extraction via a blender/juicer subjects the mixture to high shearing/centrifugal forces which introduces heat and oxygen, which degrades the nutrients and vitamins in the juice. On the other hand, cold pressing purportedly negates these effects by "gently" treating the fruit. (think your cold pressed olive oil, coconut oil etc.).

Personal opinion: Since you essentially discard the fibrous parts of the fruit (that has a ton of benefits!) and consume the sugary mixture, your body will absorb a lot of sugar in a short time. Have a whole apple instead! :)

Slight addition:

For the heat generated by a blender, you may refer to this: 
[Experiment on waste heat in a blender.](http://www.chemistryland.com/CHM107Lab/Exp06_Blender/Lab/Blender.htm) Over 3 minutes time, 9.4 degC rise was achieved in 200mL of water with a 350W blender. Of course, with fruits in the mixture the figure might vary slightly so take it with a grain of salt.

Sources:

(1) https://www.wired.com/2015/04/nobody-can-prove-cold-pressed-juice-better/

(2) http://www.ctvnews.ca/health/fact-check-are-cold-pressed-juices-worth-the-hype-1.2926121

(3) My mum bought a cold pressed juicer

Comment: hmm. I wonder how much of a temperature rise is achievable in a conventional high speed blender. I appreciate the problem with dissolved air and the unsightly browning. I wholeheartedly agree that the best juicing method is mastication in a small closed cavity called the mouth.

Comment: On a large, commercial scale, pressing is often done by heating the item being pressed external to the press to cause it to release more juice or liquid. Using olives as an example, high quality olive oil would be cold press with gently handled olives. As you go down in quality, the handling might also become rougher, more bruising, etc. By they time you get to low end utility oils the olives may get almost baked, may even be pressed, heated and pressed again to get more oil out even though much lower quality. Apples, heating may allow say 25% more juice, all of it many of us find low quality.

Comment: Is pectinase still used esp given the low yield in cold pressed juice?

Comment: @user110084 I think the answer would be no, since pectinase is an enzyme that is optimally active at around 50 degC. It would defeat the purpose of cold pressing.

Source: Wikipedia/Googling

Comment: I heard that normal juicer mixture and grinder are causing heat and that heat claims most of the nutritional items. Is that true?

Comment: @TheDictator Yes, heat can destroy certain nutritional compounds. Quite a few research has been done on this topic: eg. google on "Effects of temperature on Vitamin C in Orange Juice".

However, one of the studies do show that you'll need to achieve quite substantial temperature (>40 degC) to see a notable decrease in the vitamin C content.

Link: http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/Resources/CfENewHigher/Researching2016/fin1877.pdf